# MULE 4 : REDUCE method : Is there a limit to elements size in Reduce method if the accumulator is an Object?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

Scenario : Using Reduce method in Mule 4 to reduce a LIST into three parameters :

1. Students LIST
2. Teachers List
3. Number of Students

Using the below  Dataweave Code in Transform Message :

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload reduce((value, acc = { 'totalStudents': 0 as Number,'studentList' : [], 'teachersList' : []}) -> 
    if(
        value.age > 18 and value.age < 25
    ){
        totalStudents : (acc.totalStudents default 0 as Number) + 1,
        studentList : (acc.studentList default [] ) << {
            'studentName' : value.Name ++ " is a Student"
        }
    }else{
        teachersList : acc.teachersList default [] << value.Name ++ " is a Teacher"
    }
)
```

PROBLEM Statement: The transform message is processed successfully but in the payload I am getting only two values:

1. payload.totalStudents and
2. payload.studentList

Can anyone help me to understand why am I not getting **payload.teachersList**  in my result?

Comment: Probably the age is between 18 and 25

Comment: @SalimKhan Even if the age is between 18 and 25 of all the people in the input list, since i have defined teachersList  in ```acc = { 'totalStudents': 0 as Number,'studentList' : [], 'teachersList' : []}``` I expect to see payload.teachersList  = [] But i am not getting this payload.teachersList at all in the output

Comment: That is a variable that is initialized in acc. The output is what you are building in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this should get what you are looking for:

````
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload reduce((value, acc = { 'totalStudents': 0 as Number,'studentList' : [], 'teachersList' : []}) -> 
    if(
        value.age > 18 and value.age < 25
    ){
        totalStudents : (acc.totalStudents default 0 as Number) + 1,
        studentList : (acc.studentList default [] ) << {
            'studentName' : value.Name ++ " is a Student"
        },
        teachersList: acc.teachersList
    }else{
         totalStudents : acc.totalStudents,
         studentList : acc.studentList,
        teachersList : (acc.teachersList default [] ) <<  {'teacherName': value.Name ++ " is a Teacher"}
    }
)```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcyNf.png
````

Comment: I tried this But when I test the application locally within Studio 7 I am getting MULE FATAL JVM Error. The input list size is 40k records. I am not sure what is causing this   ```  {
  description=java.lang.StackOverflowError
  detailedDescription=java.lang.StackOverflowError
  errorType=MULE:FATAL_JVM_ERROR
  cause=org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleFatalException
  errorMessage=-
  childErrors=[]
} ```

Comment: That is a different problem altogether. I think the question was around using reduce and why certain variable declared in the acc was not showing up in the output.

Comment: You would want to make use of streaming. https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-streaming

Comment: The dataweave code had an error in my local and that was throwing the MULE_JVM Error. It seems the error in MULE is not correctly mapped. Also, your logic is correct. Values defined in "acc" in reduce method only initializes them. If we need the variables of "acc" in the payload, we will need to assign each variable some value inside both  if block and else block.

Comment: So the actually working code inspired by your code that worked for me is  attached in an  answer below. Please update your answer so that i can accept it

Comment: I think i was missing the totalStudentsCount in the else section. I updated the solution but am assuming such things can be taken care of and thus the answer could have been approved earlier. Though for accuracy sakes, i did as you requested.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
payload reduce((value, acc = { 'totalStudents': 0 as Number,'studentList' : [], 'teachersList' : []}) -> 
    if(
        value.age > 18 and value.age < 25
    ){
        totalStudents : (acc.totalStudents default 0 as Number) + 1,
        studentList : (acc.studentList default [] ) << {
            'studentName' : value.Name ++ " is a Student"
        },
        teachersList: acc.teachersList
    }else{
        totalStudents : acc.totalStudents,
        studentList : acc.studentList,
        teachersList : (acc.teachersList default [] ) <<  {'teacherName': value.Name ++ " is a Teacher"}
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps. Since there is an else condition its building the teacher list and is ignoring the student list

[image]

Answer (score 0):

And this as well.. In the input below , the else condition is met with the second element and thus the final output only contains students that are the last 4 entries in the input.

[image]